# Как реализовать взвешенный граф?

Tags: c#, графы

Граф задаётся списком смежности, читается из файла. В итоге, граф = `List<Node>` Не знаю, как программно реализовать вес рёбер. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
class Node //вершина
{
    public string name; //хранит название вершины

    //содержит названия вершин, к которым исходят дуги из данной вершины
    public List<string> neighbours = new List<string>();
    //считывание строки
    public Node(string parse)
    {
        char[] separators =
            {
                ':',
                ','
            };
        string[] parseResult = parse.Split(separators);
        name = parseResult[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < parseResult.Length; i++)
        {
            neighbours.Add(parseResult[i]);
        }
    }

    // выводит название вершины
    public void print()
    {
        if (neighbours.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("- Вершина " + name + " не имеет исходящих дуг.");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("-Вершина " + name + ":");
        Console.WriteLine("Исходящие дуги:");
        foreach (var i in neighbours)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("" + name + "-> " + i + "");
        }
    }

    /** добавляет в список вершин-"соседей"
     * вершину с заданным именем
     */
    public void addEdge(string newEdge)
    {
        neighbours.Add(newEdge);
    }

    /** удаляет из списка вершин-"соседей"
     * все вхождения deletedEdge
     */
    public void deleteEdge(string deletedEdge)
    {
        while (neighbours.Remove(deletedEdge)) ;
    }

    public void deleteEdge(int deletedEdge)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < neighbours.Count; i++)
        {
            if (int.Parse(neighbours[i]) == deletedEdge)
            {
                neighbours.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ну так храните в графе ребра, а не вершины. То есть сделайте тип ребро, который хранит инфу откуда оно идет, куда идет, и сколько весит

Comment: @tym32167 окей,а откуда мне вес брать,смежные вершины я в файле писал на подобии "1: 3, 4". И желательно не менять структуру графа. Т.к. 
"если в некоторых алгоритмах удобнее использовать список ребер - реализовать метод, преобразующий список смежности в список ребер'

Comment: я не очень понял вас, что вы хотите сделать. Но вот вам привер [отсюда](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/43mst/)  , пример как организовать [ребро](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/43mst/Edge.java.html), как орагизовать [взвешенный граф](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/43mst/EdgeWeightedGraph.java.html). Примеры на джаве, но от C# там мало что отличается

Comment: @tym32167 очень желательно оставить граф в виде "списка вершин", а не "ребёр". Т.к. если захочу список ребёр,на меня накладывается ещё одно задание
 "если в некоторых алгоритмах удобнее использовать список ребер - реализовать метод, преобразующий список смежности в список ребер ". Хочется этого избежать и реализовать с данным видом

Comment: для каждой задачи есть оптимальное прдставление графа. И вам надо уметь переключаться между ними, если вы только учитесь. Если я вас попытаюсь научить тому, что вы просите, я вам только хуже сделаю, так как пытаясь решать алгоритмы на графах с одним и тем же представлением графа, вы не только мозг себе сломаете, но и решение напишете неэффективное.

Comment: @tym32167 ну хорошо,спасибо за ссылку)

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от вида списка смежности, проще всего если для N вершин  он представлен матрицей (двумерный массив) размером NxN, где в пересечении строка-столбец записан вес ребра, например:

```
_|1|2|3|4|
1|0|7|0|0|
2|7|0|5|0|
3|0|5|0|8|
4|0|0|8|0|
```

здесь описаны 3 ребра: (1-2) весом "7"; (2-3) весом "5"; (3-4) весом "8".
"0" означает что ребро между вершинами отсутствует; веса могут быть дробными и отрицательными.
  Так можно описать взвешенный ориентированный граф, за исключением случая, когда может быть нулевой вес ребра -- придётся выдумать другой флаг отсутствия ребра, например при записи в текст.файле ставить не-числовой символ, а при написании программы (в 2-мерн.массиве чисел) использовать константу типа "NaN".

Это не список рёбер/вершин (существует только табл. смежности) -- дополнительных задач вам вроде бы не влечёт  =)